# microstack add-compute fails with "hostname 'localhost' doesn't match either of [hostname] or [ipaddress]"

Tags: openstack

Full disclosure; I'm a noob.

I am following the installation instructions @ https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install.

Multi-node OpenStack deployment, after installing the Control Node, I get the following error when trying to add the compute node:
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: ("hostname 'localhost' doesn't match either of 'black', '192.168.1.21'",)

The certificate seems ligit;
openssl x509 -text -noout -in /var/snap/microstack/common/etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem

```
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:black, IP Address:192.168.1.21
```

I can't find any documentation or references (Google) about this error.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details, and it's helpful if you provide specific details as to what you did (ie. *actual commands in case you made an error etc*) and were specific as to what command you last did that gave you the problem/error you'd like help with.

Answer (score 0):

No worries.  I just had to properly set the hosts file to contain my ip addresses and hostnames.  Dho!

Hope this helps some other noob some day.